# ValueError: Can't fetch metadata for 'googleapiclient' from PyPI

Tags: python, gmail, gmail-api, pyscript

I wonder why when I try to import third-party library googleapiclient from the class Google to send emails automatically, in **PyScript** with the `<py-env>` tag I get this error. I have been searching and searching and honestly I have not been able to solve this problem. It would be very helpful if someone could help me :)

Thank you!

```
<py-env>
        - google_auth_oauthlib
        - googleapiclient
        - paths:
            - ./Google.py
    </py-env>
```

And these are the imports of the Google class:

```
import pickle
import os
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import Flow, InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
import datetime
```

[image]

What I want to do is that the user fills the text fields, as shown in the picture, click on the button and that information is sent in a gmail mail so the person who manages that data.

## Something like this:

[image]

Comment: googleapiclient isn't built in pyodide/pyscript. You might wanna add it as [3rd-Party module](https://docs.pyscript.net/tutorials/getting-started/#packages-and-modules). You'll find the [.whl on Pypi](https://pypi.org/project/google-api-python-client/#files). There is no guarantee it will work though since some modules like [requests](https://docs.pyscript.net/latest/guides/http-requests.html) are not supported and might be needed by the modules you try to import.

Comment: @Wayne It doesn't work, because in the Python file "Google.py" if I write as you told me, it doesn't find anything, it is highlighted as error and it only works when it is `"googleapiclient"`. And I tried to install it through commands in the terminal but it doesn't work either.